# Javascript not executed when go back to previous page, behaves differently between local and live on githubpage, edge and chrome

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage, github-pages, back

Please check out this [GithubPage](https://jay0223.github.io/livetesting/) where I try to recreate an issue I had.

When you click the first button, it will create a paragraph, append it to a localstorage item and display it.

When you click the second button, it will first clear the localstorage, then redirect to another page.

Now if you click the browser back button from page2, you go back to index.html, but the paragraphs are still there. If you check the localstorage, the paragraphs are deleted, as they should, but they still display **as if the js script didn’t execute when coming back to the index.html**.

I have this problem with chrome and Firefox, but edge behaves as I expected(coming back to index.html, no paragraphs displayed). Everything was also working as expected when I test it on local live server even with chrome. But not right on a GitHub page. **Does Js script run again when visiting a page through browser’s back button?** I thought so, but can someone explain what’s going on here? Thanks.

Here is the script

```
const addPEle = document.querySelector(".addP");
const clearPEle = document.querySelector(".clearP");
const contentEle = document.querySelector(".content");

addPEle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const curContent = localStorage.getItem("content") || "";
  localStorage.setItem("content", `${curContent}<p>This is a paragraph.</p>`);
  displayContent();
});

clearPEle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("content", "");
  location.href = "page2.html";
  // displayContent();
});

function displayContent() {
  contentEle.innerHTML = "";
  const content = localStorage.getItem("content") || "There is no paragraph.";
  contentEle.innerHTML = content;
  console.log("from displayContent function");
  console.log(`content: ${content}`);
  console.log(`localStorage: ${localStorage.getItem("content")}`);
}

displayContent();
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because the [Back-Forward Cache](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#back-forward-cache) preserve your page and it's state and won't refresh your page when navigate back.

You can use the PageLifeCycle events to check if your page is navigate back and do a reload if you want. See demo https://page-lifecycle.glitch.me/ from https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/page-lifecycle

```js
window.addEventListener('pageshow', (event) => {
  if (event.persisted) {
    // page was restored from the bfcach
    // Do your reload or re-render page with data
  }
});
```

Comment: I've heard of bfcache, but I thought javascript will be executed again. Are you saying that if we don't bother with `unload` or `beforeunload` event, there is no way to execute javascript when going back to a previously visited page if the browser is bfcache enabled?

Comment: Yup. You can use the PageLifeCycle events to check if your page is navigate back and do a reload if you want. See demo https://page-lifecycle.glitch.me/ from https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/page-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

## Dirty Isolated Fix (executes when necessary).

I also used `pageshow` but have added more layers of `if` statement checks..

We had similar situation, however this only seemed to be an issue in Firefox for us (maybe a Chrome update has resolved this?) and only for the store-grid products listings, so we check that the user is on those pages as well.

Anyway, in our case because this issue was only affecting Firefox users, I used `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('firefox')` which will return `true` or `false`

so if it is true, that it is a Firefox user visiting, I will then store their current URL with `sessionStorage` as `preVisitedPage` variable, and each new page visit will compare that `currentURL` to our stored var preVisitedPage.

Funny thing that came up once I started tracking the direction a user is travelling through their browsing history is that when this issue did occur, according to how the console log was returning info, it appeared as though the user refreshed based that console says the value `0` for returning history direction (refresh), but expected was that the console would give the value of `-1` (backwards navigation) which is what was clicked; (the value `+1` would indicate forwards navigation).

We then reference our statement that checks if the current page is different from the previous session visited page. A proper refresh would be that current page and previous session visited page would be the same URL. If the previous session visited page is returning a different value for the URL than that of the current page, that we have found our bug occurring and we force a reload at this point which happens almost seamlessly.

Here is the full Javascript code:

```js
  const createFirefoxBrowsingStoreGridDirtyFix = () => {
    // Check if the browser is Firefox
    const isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('firefox');

    if (isFirefox) {
      const currentUrl = window.location.href;
      const preVisitedPage = sessionStorage.getItem('preVisitedPage');

      // Function to set 'preVisitedPage' session variable to the current URL
      const setpreVisitedPage = () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('preVisitedPage', currentUrl);
      };

      // Function to check if 'preVisitedPage' is equal to the current URL
      const isPreVisitedPage = () => {
        return currentUrl === preVisitedPage;
      };

      // Check if the URL contains 'store-grid'
      if (location.href.includes('store-grid')) { // TODO apply to Store Grid pages only
        function reorient() { // After travelling in the history stack
          const positionLastShown = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('positionLastShown'));
          let position = history.state; // Absolute position in stack

          if (position === null) { // Meaning a new entry on the stack
            position = positionLastShown + 1; // Top of stack

            // Stamp the entry with its own position in the stack
            history.replaceState( position, /*no title*/'' );
          }

          // Keep track of the last position shown
          sessionStorage.setItem( 'positionLastShown', String(position) );

          // Discover the direction of travel by comparing the two
          const direction = Math.sign( position - positionLastShown );

          // Backward (-1), reload (0) and forward (1)
          if (direction === -1) {
            // User went backwards through browsing
          } else if (direction === 0) {
            // User reloaded page (Sometimes in Firefox this is triggered with Back-button for unknown reason)

            // Check if the current page is different from the visited page
            if (!isPreVisitedPage()) {
              window.location.reload();
            }
          } else if (direction === 1) {
            // User went forward through browsing
          } else {
            // Unknown Navigation Direction
          }

          setpreVisitedPage();
        }

        addEventListener( 'pageshow', reorient );
        addEventListener( 'popstate', reorient );
      } 
    }
  };
  createFirefoxBrowsingStoreGridDirtyFix();
```

This could likely be further improved by extracting some of the cases inside the overall function, to make those more global/reusable, which would then make this function contain less code within the `createFirefoxBrowsingStoreGridDirtyFix` function.